# German Confusion: Sie Versteht

Tags: english-to-german, conjugation

So I use Duolingo for learning german, well I ran into a small learning curve I constantly have bumped into:

> Sie versteht.

If I am correct, *versteht* is both understand and understands, while *Sie* is both *She* and *They* and the rules are if it's a singular verb it's She and if it's a Plural verb it's They.

Well when I run into the sentence

> "Sie versteht deutsch."

I naturally think "They understand German" not "She understands German"

I don't know if this is a duolingo problem or if this is me missing something.

Comment: I don't really understand your question. *Sie versteht.* is singular while *Sie verstehen.* would be plural.

Comment: "Versteht is both understand and understand" What is the difference between "understand"?

Comment: @Olafant, that is technically an answer…

Comment: @CarstenS OP inclues question and answer but the interpretation contradicts it.

Comment: sorry, I meant Understand and Understands

Answer (score 6):

German conjugation can be tricky to decode for beginners. If the pronoun has multiple meanings then you have to use the form of the verb to narrow down the possibilities. In this case, the verb is in the form *versteht*, which is only used in the third person singular and informal second person plural. You can eliminate the informal second person plural because the pronoun is *ihr*, so the only possibility is *sie* meaning the third person singular ("she"). *Sie verstehen* is actually ambiguous since there is no way to distinguish between third person plural and formal second person. In other words, without additional context, *Sie verstehen* can be translated as either "You understand" or "They understand". Duolingo allows for this and should accept both possibilities.

On a side note, it's a good idea to set off words you're talking about in some way. I use quotation marks (") for words in English: This is a question about the word "question". And I use italics (*) for words in German: This is a question about the word *Frage*. Also, *versteht* would only be capitalized at the start of a sentence. Duolingo is rather lax about enforcing this kind of thing, but humans, especially native German speakers, will notice. I think you may have been trying to use capitals to set off words, as in: This is a question about the word Question. This doesn't really work and may be confusing.

Comment: The ambiguity between “sie” and “Sie” is always there, they are grammatically the same

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful.